# Как отключить звук загрузки MacOS

Tags: ios

El Capitan. iMac MK472LL/A. В системе два пользователя(администратора) и гостевая запись

Так пробовал. Не работает

```
sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%00
```

И добавить в автозагрузку скрипт, тоже

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "z$1" == "zstop" ] && nvram SystemStartupSound=" "
```

Проверяю значения, они присваиваются

```
iMac-ninazu:~ ninazu$ sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume
SystemAudioVolume   0
iMac-ninazu:~ ninazu$ sudo nvram SystemStartupSound
SystemStartupSound
```

Хуки тоже не срабатывают

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Права на хуки

```
iMac-ninazu:~ ninazu$ ls -la /Library/Scripts | grep mute
-rwxr--r--   1 root  wheel    62 Aug 23 22:01 mute-off.sh
-rwxr--r--   1 root  wheel    59 Aug 23 22:01 mute-on.sh
```

При ручном запуске скриптов. Кричит вот так

> 0:1: syntax error: ÌÂ‚¥‰ÓÏËÈ Ï‡ÍÂ не може бути розміщений тут.
>   (-2740)

Почему на укр языке. Хз, вся остальная ось на англ.

Ничего не помогает. При перезагрузке он все равно издает его.

Может что-то через Recovery Mode, или еще какие варианты есть?

Comment: второй ответ https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4001727?start=15

Comment: Тоже не отключило

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. При копировании с форума, подставился апостроф вместо одинарной кавычки.